# Обновление элемента в окне при многократном открытии

Tags: java, javafx

Случилась проблема, с которой не могу справится. 
Есть некое окно оплаты товара, которое при получении значения canPay включает разные панели. 
Проблема следующая, что при повторном открытии этого окна, панели не реагируют на команды `setVisible(true)`, но код при этом выполняется.
После оплаты, пользователь нажимает на кнопку возвращения на главное меню, затем следующий пользователь выбирает товар, жмёт оплату и при повторе не срабатывает обновление панелей

```
@FXML 
void onBack(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SerialPortException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("trade-view.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("FreedaFreeze!");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();

    Stage stageResult = (Stage) backToMenu.getScene().getWindow();
    stageResult.close();

    getClose();
}
```

Метод вызова окна:

```
@FXML
void onPay(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    ((Stage) payBtn.getScene().getWindow()).close();

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("result-view.fxml"));
    loader.load();
    Parent root = loader.getRoot();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("FreedaFreeze!");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.showAndWait();
}
```

Значения при выходе все обнуляю. Ничего не получается. Компиляцию делаю в IDE. Попробовал собрать банку, история та же самая, первый раз - работает, последующие разы - нет.

Comment: Вопрос всё ещё остаётся открытым. Сделал проверку на отображение панелей после повторного запуска - всё указывает на то, что они включены, но по факту обновления так и не происходит. Пока более менее адекватное решение, которое я нашёл - это создание отдельных окон с результатом оплаты(ошибка/успех).

Comment: Проблема может возникать из-за того, что вы не создаете новый экземпляр контроллера для каждого нового окна оплаты. Когда вы повторно открываете окно оплаты, он использует уже существующий экземпляр контроллера, и вызов **setVisible(true)** не срабатывает, потому что панели уже видимы.

Comment: У меня тоже есть такие же подозрения. Тогда как мне можно вызвать новый экземпляр контроллера и закрыть старый? Я так понимаю что '.getScene().getWindow()).close()' не полностью закрывает и очищает память. Тогда следующий вопрос, а каким образом будет правильно "вычищать" из памяти этот контроллер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее простым и адекватным решением в данном случае выделяю следующий вариант.
Создаём два дополнительных контроллера, один на успешную оплату, второй на ошибку, затем вызываем их из результирующего окна, закрывая результат.

Вызываем следующим образом: *на примере ошибки*

```
private void getError() throws IOException, SerialPortException {
    getClose();
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Stage stageResult = (Stage) cardPane.getScene().getWindow();
        stageResult.close();
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("error-view.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("FreedaFreeze!");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Очень важно обнулить все предыдущие значения, которые задаются при выполнении классов.